# What does it mean when a Ruby script starts with Gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I am working on learning Ruby and one thing that I have seen in several instances and cannot understand are scripts that start with the keyword gem.

An example can been seen in the [Sensu code](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-transport/blob/master/lib/sensu/transport/rabbitmq.rb).

```
gem "amqp", "1.3.0"

require "amqp"

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "base")
```

I understand the require statement for accessing another gem, but what does the exact *gem "amqp", "1.3.0"* mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [`gem` method that Rubygems adds to `Kernel`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Kernel.html#method-i-gem) (Rubygems is required by default in current Ruby versions). It *activates* a specific version of a gem (version 1.3.0 of the `amqp` gem in this case), meaning that the gems `lib` dir (or whatever dirs the gem specifies) is added to your `LOAD_PATH`, as are the `lib` dirs of any dependent gems it has.

It also checks that there are no version incompatibilities with any already activated gems.

All gems are activated when you use them. This normally happens when you call `require`. Calling `gem` activates the gem but doesn’t `require` any files from it, hence the line `require "amqp"` below (note the difference between `amqp` the *gem*, which the `gem` method refers to, and `amqp` the *file*, which is contained in the `amqp` gem and is what the `require` method is refering to).

This method is used to ensure you are using a specific version of a gem, without needing to use [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) (or something similar). Bundler also has a `gem` method used in `Gemfile`s, but this is a different (but similar) method.

It’s also used to specify that you want to use the gem version of a library that is also part of the standard library (say if you want to use a more recent version). For example the Yaml library distributed with Ruby is [Psych](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/v2_1_2/ext/psych) which is also [available as a gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/psych).